# JSON payload for POST sent as "System.Collections.Hashtable" instead of actual data

Tags: json, powershell, post, hash, payload

I am using Powershell to dynamically create a payload of data to be packaged up and sent on in a REST API Post Request.

My problem is that when it is recived by the API, it is listed as **System.Collections.Hashtable**. I am clearly doing something wrong here in how the data is being formatted, but nothing seems to work for me.

Here's how it is received by the API

```
{
"properties":  {
                   "recip_test":  [
                                      "System.Collections.Hashtable",
                                      "System.Collections.Hashtable"
                                  ],
                   "offending_shifts":  "MAX, OnCall-Default Shift",
                   "group_name":  "Alarmpoint Administrators"
               }
```

}

I've tried **ConvertTo-Json** as well as **+= () / .Add()** but none of those seem to work.

I am looping through an array of data which represent ID's in that array. For each item in that array (in the loop) I need to make a hash table which looks like this,

```
$recipient = @{
  'id' = $y
  'recipientType' = 'PERSON'
}
```

And then take that hash and shovel it into the payload field for **recipients** which then needs to be passed in the POST request. Below is the full code.

```
foreach($x in $collated_group_data) {
if ($x.group_name -ne 'Alarmpoint Administrators') {
    next
}

$uuid         = "***********/triggers?apiKey=**************"
$webhook_path = "$base/api/integration/1/functions/$uuid"

$payload = @{ 
    'properties' = @{
        'group_name'       = $x.group_name
        'offending_shifts' = $x.offending_shifts.Substring(0, $x.offending_shifts.Length - 2)
        'recipients'       = @()
    }
}

foreach($y in $x.supervisor_ids) {
    $payload.properties.recipients += @{'id' = $y; 'recipientType' = 'PERSON'}
}

$payload = $payload | ConvertTo-Json

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $webhook_path -Method POST -Body $payload -ContentType 'application/json'
```

}

Comment: Do you have the same issue if you use the `-Depth` parameter on `ConvertTo-Json`? You could use a higher number than the default (2): `ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100`.

Comment: That fixed it!! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use the `-Depth` parameter with a value of 3 or greater in the `ConvertTo-Json` command in this case.

```
$payload = $payload | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3
```

By default, the `-Depth` parameter is set to 2. The parameter specifies how many levels of contained objects are included in the JSON representation. You have three levels in your example.